# Почему работает protected конструктор php?

Tags: php, ооп, инкапсуляция

Почему не возникает ошибки?

```
<?php
    // Your code here!
    class One{
     public $param = 5;
      protected function __construct(){
        $this->param = 10;
        }
      public static function getInstance(){
         return new One(); 
        }
    }
    $a = One::getInstance();
    echo $a->param;
    ?>
```

Comment: а какая ошибка ожидается по-вашему и почему? про модификаторы доступа хорошо изучили тему?

Comment: из своего же класса можно вызывать любые методы, вплоть до приватных

Comment: @СергейМишин я не понимаю почему $a = new One();  не работает, а $a = One::getInstance(); работает. Как по мне, так это аналогичные записи ведь функция getInstance возвращает  new One() , что по сути и есть  $a = new One(); И в обеих случаях должен запускаться протектед конструктор.Тогда должна возникать ошибка

Comment: не аналогичные. метод `One::getInstance();` находится уже в классе. в своей капсуле, в которой действуют некоторые законы. Например внутри своей капсулы можно обращаться к своим методам и полям, не зависимо от модификаторов доступа.... а при `$a = new One();`  нет никакой капсулы - просто напрямую говоришь - эй, дай-ка мне свой метод (в данном случае конструктор это такой же метод) и на это по логике и скажет - что нельзя так делать ибо защищённый

Comment: В общем - читайте много раз про области видимости в классах.

Comment: @СергейМишин но у меня One::getInstance(); просто возвращает new One(); и тогда все равно я напрямую говорю классу что бы он дал мне свой метод. Ведь когда функция возвращает new One получается $a = new One();

Comment: @ZELIBOBA ваша ошибка  в том, что вы разворачиваете обращение к методу к более узкому. А  по факту происходит обращение к `getInstance` является обращением к **публичному** методу класса. А что он возвращает в себе - переменную, объявленную прямо в этом методе, приватные поля или сферического коня в вакууме - уже не важно. он может вернуть и экземпляр другого класса, хотя он, по вашей логике, даже не объявлен в этом классе. Т.е. вы обращаетесь к публичному методу, а делать внутри класса этот метод может всё что угодно, т.к. находится в нём же

Comment: @СергейМишин Я походу понял. Мой объект создается в строке "return new One();"  То есть создался объект внутри класса и сразу вызвался конструктор(так у меня появился доступ к protected). А потом этот объект присваивается переменной $a; . Верно?

Comment: Что-то типа того)) Объект создался внутри метода, который находится внутри класса и поэтому имеет доступ ко всем методам и свойствам этого класса.. И уже результат выполнения этого метода вернулся. и да "положился" в переменную `$a`